# How to use EasyAdmin 3.5 with singleton entity

Tags: symfony, singleton, easyadmin

Symfony 5.4 with EasyAdmin 3.5.

I have an entity `AppConfig` which single instance.

```
class AppConfig {
    /** @var AppConfig */
    protected static $instance;
    private function __construct() {}
    private function __clone() {}

    public static function getInstance() {
        if (null === self::$instance) {
            self::$instance = new self();
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }
}
```

But I've an error:

> Call to private App\Entity\AppConfig::__construct() from context
> 'EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Controller\AbstractCrudController'

which is natural, because the `__construct()` function is private.

How to use singleton class with EasyAdmin?
Thanks

Comment: Do you have a crud controller for your AppConfig entity ?
Do you want to only have one AppConfig and use easy admin to make a form easier ?

Comment: Yes. But I guess I'm on the wrong track. Maybe I should take this approach https://symfony.com/doc/current/EasyAdminBundle/actions.html#integrating-symfony-actions

Comment: You could also not make AppConfig a singleton, but limit the number of AppConfig to 1 by adding restriction on the create action.

Comment: Ok! This is an acceptable solution. Thank you very much.